# How to use add_action remove_action on specific products IDs or categories in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have this custom PHP code for a WooCommerce webshop, but I want it to only apply on 3 specific products or the whole product category. Can someone please help me with this so that the code only applies on the category "Pick & Mix" or on product IDs 707, 195 and 193?

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 1 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_usp_table', 33 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'wc_usp_table', 33 );
```

I tried searching online but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to target specific product category(ies):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary_callback', 1 );
function woocommerce_single_product_summary_callback() {
    global $product;

    if ( has_term( array('Pick & Mix'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 1 );
    
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_usp_table', 33 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'wc_usp_table', 33 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

To target instead specific product IDs replace:

```php
if ( has_term( 'Pick & Mix', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
```

with:

```php
if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 707, 195, 193 ) ) ) {
```

It will work too.